# How to mutate a state with Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, vuex, store

Having an initial state of objects array, I need to filter it with a single button with mutations, using a select tag in two different child components. In the components I'm storing the selected value in data, and passing from each component that value to the mutations via dispatch. So writing the mutations isn't working, I wonder why. By clicking the button I need to filter both components data at the same time.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hrqfyc?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FSearchBtn.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FFilters.vue,src%2Fstore%2Findex.js,src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FFlight.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FFlightList.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FArrivalPoint.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FDeparturePoint.vue

```js
// Filter component

<template>
  <select name="flights" v-model="selectedFlightClass">
  <select name="changes" v-model="selectedChanges">
  <button @click="filterFlights">Filter</button>
</template>

data() {
    return {
      selectedFlightClass: false,
      selectedChanges: false
    }
 }

methods: {
    filterFlights(filterdItems) {
      let filterdItems = {
        selectedFlightClass,
        selectedChanges
      }
      this.$store.commit('setFilteredFlights', filterdItems);
    },
  },
}

// Store

state: {
  flights: [
    {trip_class: 0, number_of_change="1"},
    {trip_class: 1, number_of_change="2"},
    {trip_class: 1, number_of_change="1"}...
  ]
}

mutations: {
  setFilteredFlights: (state, data) => {
        // from first component
      if(data.selectedFlightClass != 10) {
        return this.state.flights.filter(flight => flight.trip_class === selectedFlightClass)
      } else if(data.selectedFlightClass = 10) {
        return this.state.flights = data
      }
      //from second component
      else if(data.selectedChanges != 10) {
        return this.flights.filter(flight => flight.number_of_changes === selectedChanges)
      } else {
        return this.state.flights = data
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: return this.state.flights.filter doesn't affect anything. A mutation isn't supposed to return a result